# How to create an autosum in jquery using onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my code. I created a simple jquery file that autosum every row in my table. My problem is I can't get the correct sum of my rows. Here's what i did.

In my jquery

```
$('[id^=total]').on('change',function() {

        var index = this.id.match(/\d+/)[0];
        var total_input = parseInt($('#total'+index).val());

        var total = 0;

        $('[id^=total]').each(function(index){
            total += parseFloat($(this).val()?$(this).val():0);
        });

        var totalAll = $('#total_amt_due').val(total.toFixed(2));           
});
```

In my HTML

```
<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type='text' name='total[]' id='total1' value='' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type='text' name='total[]' id='total2' value='' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type='text' name='total[]' id='total3' value='' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type='text' name='total[]' id='total4' value='' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type='text' name='total[]' id='total5' value='' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="k-textbox" value="0.00" style="color: red; text-align: right;
                    font-family: courier" name="total_amt_due" id="total_amt_due" readonly="readonly" />
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

I created this table in PHP dynamically. But for the sake of simplicity i remove the loops. I am not good in jquery. So can you provide me a simple answer for creating the autosum?

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rochellecanale/K8UNQ/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a problem with the row that shows sum of totals because it's id also starts with "total".
Just change its id (lets say to amt_due instead of total_amt_due):

```
<td>
         <input type="text" class="k-textbox" value="0.00" style="color: red; text-align: right; font-family: courier" name="total_amt_due" id="amt_due" readonly="readonly" />
     </td>
```

Check this out : [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/K8UNQ/4/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var total = 0;
$('[id^=total]').on('change', function () {
    if ($.trim($(this).val()) != '') {
        total += parseFloat($(this).val() ? $(this).val() : 0);
    }
    var totalAll = $('#total_amt_due').val(total.toFixed(2));
});
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/K8UNQ/5/)**

Comment: @AlexArt.Hey Alex thanks for identifying error, if it has. Can you please tell me where i am wrong.

Comment: The problem is not in logic or implementation of your answer. You can check my answer to see what was the problem